# How to Access Spring Application Configuration Values based on Requests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In one of my Spring Boot application, I have a controller that needs to read from application.yml for accessing an external API. I have organization setup in the external API, similar to github organization, and each organization comes with its own client ID and secret key.

My application.yml looks something like this.

```
organization:
  abc:
    client:
      clientId: f29e347add73
      clientSecret: dad2404e63ec4cd   

  xyz:
    client:
      clientId: 0884340cf3e793
      clientSecret: a26ff0119d907e9
```

Currently, I can pick up a property value in my controller like this.

```
@Value("${organization.abc.client.clientId}")
private String abcClientId;
@Value("${organization.abc.client.clientSecret}")
private String abcClientSecret;
```

But what I need to do is, instead of hardcoding, if a request for `abc` comes, the configuration for `abc` is picked up and when for `xyz` comes, the configuration for `xyz` is picked up. Same for any number of the organization I keep adding to the application.yml file.

Please help me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can rewrite your `applicaiotn.yml` as follows, you can read it into a list of object with`@ConfigurationProperties`.

```
organization:
  list:
    -
      name: abc
      client:
        clientId: f29e347add73
        clientSecret: dad2404e63ec4cd
    -
      name: xyz
      client:
        clientId: 0884340cf3e793
        clientSecret: a26ff0119d907e9
```

Create a class to map properties to list of object:

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="organization")
public class ConfigurationService {
    private List<Org> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //getters and setters

    public static class Org {
        private String name;
        private Client client;
        //getters and setters
    }

    public static class Client {
        private String clientId;
        private String clientSecret;
        //getter and setter
    }
}
```

Now you can access this list like...

```
@Autowired
ConfigurationService configurationService;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can inject an [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) (initialized by default by Spring Boot) like this:

```java
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

And then use it like:

```java
env.getProperty("my-property")
```

Comment: I am not trying to access a standalone property.

Comment: What do you mean by standalone property? This method lets you retrieve any property defined in your `application.yml`.

Comment: @Gaustavo if you check the question, what I mean is, I can have multiple property keys, `organization.abc.client.clientId` ,  `organization.xyz.client.clientId`, and so on. If you see, the organization names `abc` and `xyz` are the only variables. Based on request, I wan't pick one. For example if request is for abc, `organization.abc.client.clientId` gets picked. Similarly, if request is 'xyz', `organization.xyz.client.clientId` gets picked.

Comment: Sure, and given that you know which organization it is, you could retrieve its properties with `env.getProperty("organization." + orgCode + ".client.clientId")` and `env.getProperty("organization." + orgCode + ".client.clientSecret")`, where `orgCode` is, for example, `abc`, couldn't you?